# Estimating aggregate production function with sharp decline during a crisis period

Tags: aggregate-production, economic-crisis

How could one go about estimating a long term aggregate production function, when there is a sharp decline in both factor inputs (i.e. investment and hours worked) and output for a few consecutive periods?
I have seen some research, where the authors either adapt a regime-switching errors technique [Bartkus, A., 2016](http://www.zurnalai.vu.lt/ekonomika/article/download/10122/8178) (although this technique was used in forecasting GDP as a random-walk process, and not estimating a production function), and in another - the authors omitted the "undesireable", "anomalous" data (the three or four consecutive quarters that the sharp fall in GDP was observed in the GFC) from the estimation alltogether.

---

What other, robust, methods are used when estimating the aggregate production function from such heteroscedastic(?) time-series data? Without going too much into business cycle theory teritory.